# How to use firebase authentication separately for admin and client?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I have 2 apps added in a single firebase project. One app is for admins and another for clients. There may be more than 1 admins and anyone can be both client and admin. If a single person wants to be both client and admin,i want to make the app such that he can have different passwords as client or as admin. So is there any way we can use a single email in 2 different apps with different passwords.

Answer (score 0):

A single account in Firebase Authentication has (at most) one password for the email+password provider. Think of it this way: authentication is where the user proves who they are, and a person using a different app is still the same person.

If you insist on having them providing different credentials, you can consider having them create two separate accounts, with variations on their email address. Most email providers map addresses in the form `user+alias1@domain.com` and `user+alias2@domain.com` to the same mailbox.

Comment: I agree. This approach is great but the problem arises in email verification.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that?